# How to list only the visible items in QTableView in pyqt

Tags: pyqt4, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have below code to get filters for QTableView. But i am not able to filter multiple column at a time.

i.e., if filter column 2 with `row 0 col 0` and try to filter column 2, it should show only the visible unique values of `column 2` (probably it should show `row 0 col 1` only) but now its showing all the elements of `column 2` (`row 0 col 1`, `row 1 col 1`, `row 2 col 1`)

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class myWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget  = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.lineEdit       = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.view           = QtGui.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox       = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.label          = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("Regex Filter")

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        for rowName in range(3) * 5:
            self.model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
                [   QtGui.QStandardItem("row {0} col {1}".format(rowName, column))    
                    for column in range(3)
                    ]
                )

        self.proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Column {0}".format(x) for x in     range(self.model.columnCount())])

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged)

        self.horizontalHeader = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):
        self.logicalIndex   = logicalIndex
        self.menuValues     = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        self.signalMapper   = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)  

        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(self.logicalIndex)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)

        valuesUnique = [    self.model.item(row, self.logicalIndex).text()
                            for row in range(self.model.rowCount())
                            ]

        actionAll = QtGui.QAction("All", self)
        actionAll.triggered.connect(self.on_actionAll_triggered)
        self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
        self.menuValues.addSeparator()

        for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(list(set(valuesUnique)))):              
            action = QtGui.QAction(actionName, self)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)  
            action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)  
            self.menuValues.addAction(action)

        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)  

        headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())        

        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(self.logicalIndex)

        self.menuValues.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  "",
                                    QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                    QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                    )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  stringAction,
                                    QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitive,
                                    QtCore.QRegExp.FixedString
                                    )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        search = QtCore.QRegExp(    text,
                                QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app  = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = myWindow()
    main.show()
    main.resize(400, 600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i run the above code i get the below output

[image]

When i click on Column 2 Header the filter list displayed is as below and its showing correctly (Unique values in that column)...

[image]

When i select `row 0 col 1` in the displayed filter, i get the following filtered list

[image]

But again when i click on the Column 2 header for filter it shows the same list as my 1st image. All the unique items of column 2 (from model view) and not from proxyfilter. Actually it should show only `row 0 col 1` as unique items in Column 2 are only `row 0 col 1`

[image]

Comment: This is a lot of code and your question is unclear. Are you simply asking how to apply a filter to multiple columns?

Comment: @jdi yes jdi you can consider it as filter multiple, i have uploaded images for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are still using the source model to look up the rows. Data in the original model does not change. Only the filter proxy model reflects the filtered changes.

So you just need to modify your lookup in your (really long named) `on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked` slot:

```
valuesUnique = [    
    self.proxy.index(row, self.logicalIndex).data().toString()
    for row in xrange(self.proxy.rowCount())
]
```

You could also remove a few of the conversion for the unique set:

```
valuesUnique = set(    
    self.proxy.index(row, self.logicalIndex).data().toString()
    for row in xrange(self.proxy.rowCount())
)
...
for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(valuesUnique)): 
    ...
```

And just a small other thing I wanted to point out. You are keeping around a couple of temp objects that don't ever get deleted. In that same slot, you create a new `QMenu` and `QSignalMapper` every time but you never clean up the old ones. Over time you are just making more and more.

For the `QMenu`, just make it a local variable and don't parent it to `self`. That way it will get cleaned up after it disappears. And for the `QSignalMapper`, you can just use a `deleteLater` call before creating a new one:

```
# local variable, and no parent
menuValues = QtGui.QMenu()

# delete the previous one
try:
    self.signalMapper.deleteLater()
except:
    pass

self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
```

Comment: Thx justin, its working perfectly... really u r awesome. One small thing how can i have dropdown icon like combobox at header. Anyhow i will open a new post this.